# more efficient way to inset values into a mysql table

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Collection and I want to write Nodes' values into a mysql table. Right now I connect to the database, create a statement and then for each Node in the collection I run

```
// open the connection then
Statement statement = connect.createStatement();
for (Node n : vertices) {
   statement.execute("INSERT INTO " + table + " (name, department) values ('" + n.getName() + "', '" + n.getOrgId() + "')");
}
// then I close the connection
```

I am wondering if is there a more efficient method to deal with such a task.

Comment: you can use [batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) Also please try to implement using [preparedstatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Add every query to the statement as batch ([Statement#addBatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch(java.lang.String))) and execute the batch after the for loop

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use prepared statements:

```
String query = "insert into " + table + " (name, department) values (?,?)";
try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    for(Node n : vertices) {
        ps.setString(1, n.getName());
        ps.setInt(2, n.getOrgId());
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
} catch(SQLException e) {
    // Exception handling
}
```

Notice that because of the way your query is built it is still vulnerable to SQL injection attacs (because you are building the string with a variable `table`). I recommend you either remove the `table` variable or take measures to ensure that that variable is never visible by any user of your program.

Answer (score 1):

Try to prepare the query for a multiple insert, then execute it at once:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (name, department) values";
for (Node n : vertices) {
   query += " ('" + n.getName() + "', '" + n.getOrgId() + "')");
}

statement.execute(query);
```

Comment: You are missing a comma to separate the inserted values: `insert into tbl (field1, field2) values (v11, v12), (v21, v22), ..., (vn1,vn2);` Also, your query does not helps to solve the SQL injection attack risk.

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple rows at the same time.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

[Check this Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)